# Getting a "401 Unauthorized" error when running the Twitter bot (Tweepy Client API v2)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I run this code:

```py
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=" CONSUMER KEY ",
    consumer_secret=" CONSUMER SECRET ",
    access_token=" ACCESS TOKEN ",
    access_token_secret=" ACCESS TOKEN SECRET "
)

following = client.get_users_following(1550947094185349127)

print(following)
```

And got the following response:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\bot\Tests.py", line 11,
> in 
> following = client.get_users_following(1550947094185349127)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\totes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py",
> line 2147, in get_users_following
> return self._make_request(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\totes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py",
> line 129, in _make_request
> response = self.request(method, route, params=request_params,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\totes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py",
> line 98, in request
> raise Unauthorized(response) tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized Unauthorized

I should mention my API keys are correct, as I am using them for another code that works with no problem.

Comment: For safety purposes, don't expose your private keys to the public. Use filler text instead.

Comment: oh thanks i forgot to do this